# SELinux woes developing systemd extension

Tags: systemd, selinux

All,

I'm developing a modification to systemd that will extend systemd-sleep to support calling user-defined scripts on suspend, hybrid-sleep, etc. similar to systemd-sleep. This is working quite well, however when I started testing on an SELinux-enabled system, things began to fall apart.

I'm not well versed in SELinux, so I'm not even sure on where to begin looking. Fundamentally, the service calls a script as a configured user (/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep-user) which in turn executes any executable under `$HOME/.config/systemd/system-sleep`.

The associated error message is: `SELinux is preventing systemd-sleep-u from execute_no_trans access on the file /home/stallion/.config/systemd/system-sleep/kill-scdaemon.sh.`

Since this behavior is similar to how systemd-sleep works (albeit, it uses /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep) I was hoping this would just require applying the same properties to the user location.

Any thoughts?

**Edit**: Relevant audit log entry below:

> type=AVC msg=audit(1508702442.885:388): avc:  denied  {
>   execute_no_trans } for  pid=3539 comm="systemd-sleep-u"
>   path="/home/stallion/.config/systemd/system-sleep/kill-scdaemon.sh"
>   dev="dm-3" ino=533984 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0
>   tcontext=system_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

Comment: There should be an exact AVC message logged in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, it probably relevant enough to include in the question.

Comment: I don't have a system to test on; could you add [`SELinuxContext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#SELinuxContext=) to systemd service file? This would make your scripts run in unconfined domain, in which SELinux does not place (almost any) restrictions. (I can write this as an answer should this work)

Comment: It definitely works, but you it looks like you can't mix `User=` and `SELinuxContext=`. I was able to work around this by just using `runuser` so I'm good to go. I'd love to see a write up on why this works. Thanks!

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5875

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because there is no rule in SELinux policy to allow the specific access: allow non-transitioning execution of a file with context *config_home_t* by a process running in *init_t* domain.

You could create a custom policy module to include such rule, but you probably do not want to allow *any* init process to execute *any* file with user home data label. Another option is to create a custom policy which contains a new file context for your scripts, matching labeling rules and rules allowing a process in *init_t* domain to execute them.

Third option (and likely the simplest option) is to configure systemd to execute the process in [*unconfined domain*](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Targeted_Policy-Unconfined_Processes.html), in which SELinux places almost no restrictions (regular DAC, etc. restrictions still apply). Use `SELinuxContext` option in your systemd service file:

```
SELinuxContext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again for the help and explanation!